# Error starting Selendroid session

Tags: python, selenium, selendroid

I am trying to test a website functioning using selendroid.
I first launch the emulator :

```
emulator -avd <device>
```

then I started the selendroid server :

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.15.0-with-dependencies.jar
```

After that, I launched the python test:

```
python test.py
```

However, after some executions, the device chrashes and selendroid could not find it. adb stops logging and then I had "Error starting selendroid session".

So, I have to restart the adb server.

Does someone knows what to do to keep the device connected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are starting the selendroid server from the command line. Just use this.

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.15.0-with-dependencies.jar -keepAdbAlive
```